# Extract all digits values after first underscore

Tags: r, regex, string

I want to extract the numbers after the 1st underscore `(_)`, but I don't know why just only 1 number digit is selected.

My sample data is:

```
myvec<-c("increa_0_1-1","increa_9_25-112","increa_25-50-76" )
as.numeric(gsub("(.*_){1}(\\d)_.+", "\\2", myvec))
[1]  0  9 NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

I'd like:

```
[1]  0  9 25
```

Please, any help with it?

Comment: How about `as.numeric(gsub("[^_]*_(\\d+).*", "\\1", myvec))`. If you use `(\\d)` that will only capture a single digit. If you want one or more use `(\\d+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract the first number after the first underscore, you can use a capture group with `str_match` and the pattern `_([0-9]+)`

Note to repeat the character class (or `\\d+`) one or more times.

For example

```
library(stringr)

myvec<-c("increa_0_1-1","increa_9_25-112","increa_25-50-76" )

str_match(myvec,  "_([0-9]+)")[,2]
```

Output

```
[1] "0" "9" "25"
```

See a [R demo](https://ideone.com/23ZmzQ)

Answer (score 3):

Some explanation. We are interested in digits coming after `_`. `[0-9]` captures the digits, where the `+` says that we want to match any number of digits in a row. `(?<=_)` 'looks behind' the digit and makes sure we are only capturing digits preceded by a `_`.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(myvec, "(?<=_)[0-9]+")
```

```
[1] "0"  "9"  "25"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, based on `stringr::str_extract`:

```r
library(stringr)

myvec<-c("increa_0_1-1","increa_9_25-112","increa_25-50-76" )

as.numeric(str_extract(myvec, "(?<=_)\\d+"))

#> [1]  0  9 25
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sub` (because you will need a single search and replace operation) with a pattern like `^[^_]*_(\d+).*`:

```r
myvec<-c("increa_0_1-1","increa_9_25-112","increa_25-50-76" )
sub("^[^_]*_(\\d+).*", "\\1", myvec)
# => [1] "0"  "9"  "25"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/Row9oH) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MDJmW9/1).

*Regex details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^_]*` - a negated character class that matches any zero or more chars other than `_`
- `_` - a `_` char
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to the value captured into this group from the replacement pattern): one or more digits
- `.*`  - the rest of the string (`.` in TRE regex matches line break chars by default).

Answer (score 0):

```
myvec<-c("increa_0_1-1","increa_9_25-112","increa_25-50-76" )
as.numeric(gsub("[^_]*_(\\d+).*", "\\1", myvec))
[1]  0  9 25
```